# Rendering base64 PDF data on phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

For my phonegap app, I am using Javascript to get Base64 data from the SQLite browser DB then render on the browser. It works well when testing using Safari on the Imac (i.e before building and deploying as an app)  Once I deploy the app to the Ipad device,  the PDF refuses to render. On the Xcode debugger console, I get the following error:-

**2011-12-06 10:58:11.360 ThinkHealth-Touch[7823:707] PhoneGapDelegate::shouldStartLoadWithRequest: Received Unhandled URL data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQgdmVyeXBkZi5jb20KMyAwIG9iag....(pdf data)...PRg0K**

The following is the jscript code implementing the rendering..
try

```
{
//lsPdfData contains the data
var lsPdfData = PagePAPDF.fobjPAPDF.getPAPDF();
    if(lsPdfData!=null || lsPdfData !=undefined)
    {
lsPdfData = "data:application/pdf;base64," + lsPdfData.replace(/!/g, "+");
document.getElementById('ObjPaPdf').setAttribute('data', lsPdfData);
DivPAPdf.innerHTML = DivPAPdf.innerHTML;
    }else
    {
    ONSUtils.ShowONSMessageBox("error", "Bla bla bla");
    }
    }catch(e)
    {
    ONSUtils.ShowONSMessageBox("error", "An Error occured while trying to render the PDF File.Please try again- "+ e.message);
    }
```

Anybody with an idea why iget this error? 
Any idea how else i can render the PDF  from base 64